# Need up to date way to implement activity with tabs connect to fragments? while ActionBar.TabListener is deprecated, TabLayout can't be resolved

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-tabs

I need activity with multiple tabs that connect to fragments. I have found using ActionBar.TabListener, however, it is depreciated in API Level 21. Also, when using TabLayout, Android Studio tells me it can't resolve it!!

Can anyone suggest a more up to date way to do this?

Comment: Could you attach a picture of the layout you'd like to implement? It is not clear what you're trying to achieve. Also post the code you currently have and the error messages you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabLayout can help.

Before using TabLayout, you need to add `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'` to your build.gradle.

You can read [this page](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) for further information.

Comment: If you have any good resources about using TabLayout, send it plz.
Thanks in advance :)